# Edit many same name isolated variables at a time in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table. Each cell can hold its value as a string or the edit in place template for that datatype.

I render one thing or the other based on the value of the variable "ttt" of that table cell. If ttt=true it renders the editing template if false it renders the value as string.

The way things are set up you can toggle between true and false of a specific cell each time you double-click on it.

I wish to have as well a button at top of the page that toggles all the "ttt" variables between true or false at the same time for all the table cells.

What is the best way to do this the way I have things set up.

Here is the template of the table:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="editabletable">
  <div ng-controller="listeditorController" cg-busy="{promise:myPromise, message:'&nbsp;'}">

      <div tasty-table bind-resource-callback="getResource" bind-init="init" bind-filters="filterBy">
        <div class="table-responsive" style="width:100%;">

          <table class="superResponsive" adapt-table style="width:{{theWidth}};margin:0 auto;">


              <thead>
              <!-- <thead tasty-thead bind-not-sort-by="notSortBy"></thead> -->
              <tr>
                <th style="max-width:{{columnWidth}}px;" ng-repeat="attobj in rows[0].class_attributes()">
                  {{ attobj.label }}
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="max-width:{{columnWidth}}px;" ng-repeat="attobj in header.columns track by $index">
                  <input ng-if="attobj.filterable" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="filterBy[attobj.filterkey || attobj.key]" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

              <tr ng-repeat="dbo in rows">
                <td style="max-width:{{columnWidth}}px;" ng-repeat="attobj in header.columns" ng-dblclick="ttt=!ttt">

                <div>
                  <form name="theForm" novalidate>
                  <div ng-if="ttt" ng-init="attobj = attobj.attobj" ng-include src="getAttValuesEditorTemplate(dbo, attobj)">
                  </div>
                  </form>
                  <div ng-if="!ttt" ng-repeat="v in dbo.get4(attobj.key) track by $index">
                    <p ng-if="v.cid">{{ v.displayName() }}</p>
                    <p ng-if="!v.cid">{{ v }}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>

        </div>
        <div tasty-pagination bind-list-items-per-page="listItemsPerPage" bind-items-per-page="itemsPerPage" bind-template-url="'/templates/table/pagination.html'"></div>
      </div>

  </div>
</script>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Numerous ways you could do it...what have you tried?

Comment: Well I thought i could set up "ttt" as scope variable within a controller of the whole table but than I would sacrifice the individual toggle cell by cell so I wasn´t sure of how to affect all the ttt variables of all the cells at the same time without scarifying what I had already set up

Comment: Keep in mind that ng-repeat creates child scopes. So a directive within `ng-repeat` will have access to instances of `ttt`. I'm not exactly sure what best approach for performance will be but a simple one to start is broadcast events and set `ttt` in `$.on` listener

Comment: Ok, so if I create a directive of the main table that holds all the cells I should be able to check the number of child scope variables of the name "ttt" loop through them all and set there validity to true?

Comment: I don't think so because `ttt` is being created in cell level child scopes from what I can tell. put directive in cell

Comment: But how will anything from there apply on other cells value for "ttt"?

Comment: Not sure what that means. Do you understand the concept of `ng-repeat` child scopes?

Comment: Yes I understand them

Comment: So what I was suggesting was try a broadcast perhaps from main controller level and listen in cell level directive where you have access to that `ttt` in the scope

Comment: What you mean by broadcast & listen

Comment: angular scope events. Look for `$broadcast` and `$on` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Ok thanks i´ll give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution I came up with is fairly simple but SLOW.

I added a controller at the table level which defines a scope variable "editGird" defined on load as "false".

On click of the button "Edit gird" the scope variable "editGird" toggles between true and false.

If set to true the cell is rendered like:

```
<td ng-if="editGird==true" style="max-width:{{columnWidth}}px;" ng-repeat="attobj in header.columns">
        <div>
          <form name="theForm" novalidate>
            <div ng-init="attobj = attobj.attobj" ng-include src="getAttValuesEditorTemplate(dbo, attobj)">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
</td>
```

If editGird == false:

```
<td ng-if="editGird==false" style="max-width:{{columnWidth}}px;" ng-repeat="attobj in header.columns" ng-dblclick="ttt=!ttt">
                <div>
                  <form name="theForm" novalidate>
                  <div ng-if="ttt" ng-init="attobj = attobj.attobj" ng-include src="getAttValuesEditorTemplate(dbo, attobj)">
                  </div>
                  </form>
                  <div ng-if="!ttt" ng-repeat="v in dbo.get4(attobj.key) track by $index">
                    <p ng-if="v.cid">{{ v.displayName() }}</p>
                    <p ng-if="!v.cid">{{ v }}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
</td>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('editGirdController', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {     

      $scope.editGird= false;
      $scope.onOff = function() {
          if ($scope.editGird == true){
            $scope.editGird = false;
            $scope.editGirdColor ='#0887A7';
          } else{
            $scope.editGird = true;
            $scope.editGirdColor ='lightGreen';
          }
      console.log($scope.editGird); 
      console.log($scope);
      }

    }
]);
```

But this is very very slow!!!
On tables which have 25-35 columns it takes 1 second for each 5 rows to render!!!
How can I make this more efficient???

[image]